# Is there a way to find date format defined on a Excel column?

Tags: python, date

We have multiple data files coming in from different sources in Excel format. There is a date column (`x_date`) on this file which can have data in different date format. The date formats are not always known in advance and also there are few sources which send this data in string (column format is either General/Text) form.

Is there a way to read incoming data irrespective of date format and convert it to a common date format?

Comment: I find it hard to believe there is such way. How will the program know if in `2019/02/03` the `03` is month or day if it's changing between values?

Comment: It's possible in pandas

Comment: @toRex: I don't believe that.

Comment: Find the code here: https://gist.github.com/mhhabib/b8ab88264a7fac7c3a444c53117ae67e

Comment: @toRex , thank you for sharing the code example. I tried the same method to convert the date values in incoming source data. but it does not work correctly for all values. If you look at your example data the date of first record (4/7/61) was translated with year as "2061", which I guess is not correct.  Instead the last record is showing correct date value.

Comment: Your incoming data are also showing the same as `7/4/61` and it's converted to '2061-07-04`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `panda` library. To convert any date to you preferable format hope it will work.

```
import pandas as pd

customer_calls = pd.read_excel("CustomerCalls.xlsx")

# Output with dates converted to YYYY-MM-DD
customer_calls["DateTime Recorded"] = pd.to_datetime(customer_calls["DateTime Recorded"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
customer_calls.to_excel("CustomerCalls_YYYY_MM_DD.xlsx")
```

See the full illustration in [gist](https://gist.github.com/mhhabib/b8ab88264a7fac7c3a444c53117ae67e) code.